# Finding the radius of convergence of a complex series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the radius of convergence of the following complex series:
$$\sum_{n}{\sqrt{n}(4 + (-1)^n)z^n}.$$

What I did is this:

for $n$ even:
$c_n = \sqrt{n}(4 + 1) = 5\sqrt{n}$

$\limsup \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} = 1$

and I get the same thing when $n$ is odd

since $\limsup \sqrt{c_n} \leq \limsup \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$.

The radius of convergence is then $1/1 = 1$.

is this in any way correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your answer is not fully correct.

The radius of convergence is 1 because by the Squeeze Theorem,
$$1\leftarrow(3\sqrt{n})^{1/n} \leq (c_n)^{1/n}\leq (5\sqrt{n})^{1/n}\to 1$$
where $c_n:=\sqrt{n}(4 + (-1)^n)>0$.
Moreover,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{c_{2n+1}}{c_{2n}}=\frac{3}{5}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{c_{2n+2}}{c_{2n+1}}=\frac{5}{3}.$$
which implies that
$$\liminf_{n\to +\infty}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}=\frac{3}{5}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}=\frac{5}{3}.$$

Comment: so the radius of convergence is actually $\frac{3}{5}$ ?

Comment: please can you explain the implication of the last 2 lines?

Comment: @HexaFlexagon The implication is that in this case the limit of the ratio does not  exists (it is useless for finding the radius of convergence).

Comment: thank you so much, it's clear now